# Deploy Ionic 2 app to web - images not showing

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, webdeploy

I'm trying to deploy my Ionic 2 app to my university's web server. But when I copy and upload my projects www folder my css-images in the app aren't there.

My app works as it should on the web, and some of my components scss is showing except the images..

Here's my page Search.scss:

```
 page-search {

  .bg-image {
    background-image: url('../../assets/img/backgroundstars.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 2;
  }
```

As you can see, my images is in the assets/img folder, but I've tried to move it to www/img but my background picture doesn't show then either

Comment: your relative path is incorrect. `../assets/img/backgroundstars.jpg` Check the dupe

Answer (score 0):

```
.bg-image {

    background: url("../assets/img/backgrounds/backgroundstars.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;

    -webkit-background-size: cover;

    -moz-background-size: cover;

    background-size: cover;

}
```

try this...

Comment: that almost worked! When I now upload the www to my server but my background is all black.. But I can't see my background image.. And my url is not "../assets/img/backgrounds/backgroundstars.jpg" as you wrote. It's "img/backgroundstars.jpg"

Comment: Also, here's how my project solution looks like:
https://imgur.com/a/TTQ9z